# how can I constantly refresh an individual div conserving the id of the post?

Tags: php, ajax

I am doing a blog with PHP, AJAX, MySQL, etc. As usual, each post has its ID and inside the posts you can see the comments.

What I am trying to do is refresh the comment's `div` by calling the `comments.php` document with AJAX and putting it in the `div` with `$('#comments').html(data);`.

Doing this every 5 seconds for maintaining the comments like in real time, but the problem is that when the `div` does the first refreshing, the `div` loses the ID of the post and say that is `undefined`.

How can I refresh any `div` without losing the ID of the post?

If I call the `comments.php` file with the typical `include(file.php)` inside of the post file, I have no problem, but using this way I just can't refresh the content.

Here's the code:

post.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $.ajax({  
        url: 'support/comments.php',  
        success: function(data) {  
            $('#comments').html(data);  
        }  
    });    
});  
</script>
```

`div` where the result is going to be showed:

```
<div id="comments">
</div>
```

Script for refreshing the `div`:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
function refreshDivs(divid, secs, url) {
    // define our vars
    var divid,secs,url,fetch_unix_timestamp;

    // The XMLHttpRequest object
    var xmlHttp;
    try {
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                alert("your browser doesn't support ajax.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Timestamp para evitar que se cachee el array GET
    fetch_unix_timestamp = function () {
        return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))
    }
    var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();
    var nocacheurl = url+"?t="+timestamp;

    // the ajax call
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            setTimeout(function(){refreshDivs(divid,secs,url);},secs*1000);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET",nocacheurl,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
window.onload = function startrefresh () {
    //update content on real time
    refreshDivs('comments',10,'support/comments.php'); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is refreshDivs?

Comment: *update* its content

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the post id in the URL, like so:

```
url: 'support/comments.php?id=<?= $post_id ?>'
```

Then wrap the call with a setTimeout, like so:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({  
        url: 'support/comments.php?id=<?= $post_id ?>',  
        success: function(data) {  
            $('#comments').html(data);  
        }  
    });
}, 5000);
```

And discard refreshDiv.

This is assuming that comments.php retrieves the comments, and some other code posts them.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work... it doesn't matter if I am using friendly urls?... actually comments.php also post the comments

Comment: in comments.php I tried to get the id with $id=intval($_GET['n']); but it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

ok guys I solved it... I am gonna leave the code here in case of somebody could has the same problem... what I did was build a hidden input and put this input to use its value like the id of the post, then I sent the value of this input to the script with #('div').val and finally I sent that value to the comments.php file, once there.... I used the value in the query sentence for doing the comparative and finally can get the comments in the right post

Here's the code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(function(){
//Comentarios
              var id = $("#idcomment").val();
        $.get("support/comments.php", { idpost: id }, function(LoadPage){
        $("#comment").html(LoadPage);
        });
    }, 5000); 
    });
</script>
```